# DUO 3D Mini Sensor by Code Laboratories

Tags: image-processing, camera, stereo-3d

Can any one tell me the maximum depth range that I can get using DUO 3D Stereoscopic camera by Code Laboratories? Details can be found at https://duo3d.com/public/pdf/CL_DUO_MINI_PB_1.1.pdf. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect a working range of around 25cm - 2.5m with some variation depending on the scene and lighting. We have several videos to give you a better idea of what is possible with standard algorithms. Specifically this one may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKZtILPnvX4